# Complex Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have four types of strings, as shown below.  The difference is that the two numbers `(23)` and `(15)` may be there in string or not be there.

```
(23) Abc 11 (15) Krtss 14 (25:05 IN 2ND)
Abc 11 (15) Krtss 14 (25:05 IN 2ND)
(23) Abc 11 Krtss 14 (25:05 IN 2ND)
Abc 11 Krtss 14 (25:05 IN 2ND)
```

The Text `Abc` and `Krtss` can be any two names.  These names may even contain spaces or hyphens.

I need:

1. A single regular expression to extract "Abc" from all 4 strings.
2. A second single regular expression to extract "Krtss" from all 4 strings.

Here `Abc` and `Krtss` are two names and may contain spaces and hyphens also.

If a single regex is not possible, please give me a small PHP code snippet to get the desired output.

Comment: I suggest http://www.rubular.com/ for playing around with regexen and seeing results as you type.

Comment: @deceze - What do you think about [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)?

Comment: @Jared "...is a graphical application for ***Windows***..." Sorry, not much. ;o) At least it's not as easy to simply link people to. :)

Comment: @user: "Please give me a code" is not the domain of SO. It's about technical and educative explanations foremost. This is why some attempt to solve it yourself beforehand is commonly expected.

Comment: @deceze - Oops, I thought it was cross-platform (guess I was thinking about the Lispness).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to review the [faq]. Also, you'll need to post some code as to what you've tried and what's failing. We're here to help with problems, not do your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a simple answer to get the two names, then do this:

```
/.+?(\w[\w\s-]*) \d+.*? ([\w\s-]+) \d+ \(/
```

Note that for the first name I'm enforcing that it start with a letter, so as to avoid accidentally eating up the space after the first parenthesized number, if it is present. If that isn't a problem, you can make the first part of the regex inside parens the same as the second one.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Both the names will start with a letter. Only thing i will have to do is concatenate a space at the start of all the strings so that it works in all cases without removing first letter.